# Scikit-learn error dataset "load_breast_cancer"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm

Trying to run a code using sklearn (in windows, pycharm). Although `import data load_breast_cancer` is not working. Below is the complete code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

data = load_breast_cancer()

label_names = data['target_names']
labels = data['target']
feature_names = data['feature_names']
features = data['data']

print(label_names)
print(labels[0])
print(feature_names[0])
print(features[0])
```

The error says
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.datasets'; 'sklearn'`

I have already installed scikit and its datasets using
`pip install -U scikit-learn`  and `pip install -U scikit-datasets`.
I also tried installing it in pycharm interpreter...

Here are some images from my pycharm:

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1f7G.png [I already installed scikit-learn in the interpreter]

[2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2FFX.png [The error]

Comment: Can you share the output of ```import sklearn ; dir(sklearn)```?

Comment: its working fine on colab,  `from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer`

Comment: It looks like you have not installed in the current path. Use `!pip install scikit-learn` in jupyter notebook

Comment: Same error when i tried `import sklearn ; dir(sklearn)` .

Comment: I tried using colab and it does work fine

Comment: This is a directory problem regarding pip install, kindly refer to that topic, I think there are some questions which might have useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try pip install sklearn, that should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).